# How to use file to manage navigation goals?

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Application**: Save several pose and quaternion pairs into a file and load them to plan a navigation which has several intermediate stops.

**Background:** I'm developing nodes that can receive user's command and save current pose/quaternion data of robot into a file(e.g. yaml file or bag file) in an sequence. This is called task planning.

I will also make a node that can load that file and make the robot go to goals in sequence recorded in that file. This is called task replaying.

**Question:** Is there any tool/ros_package that I can use?

My plan now is using the `yaml file` and the `yaml-library-for-python` that can handle `.yaml` files.
Also, rbbg mentioned the `.bag` file solution. Thank him~

Thank You!

ps: if there is any puzzles, feel free to ask me. :-)

========================================

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250586/how-to-use-file-to-manage-navigation-goals?/) by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2016-12-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Sonictl,

I find the easiest way to handle this kind of file IO from ROS is to use rosbags. Very easy to use and you can save and load ros msgs without the need for parsing etc. Have a look at the [rosbag cookbook](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook) and the [rosbag code API](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API) for some examples on how to use it.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2016-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0